# Adding show more and shore less in app from a long text

Tags: flutter

Have used this package   flutter_html: ^1.0.2 to interpret some html tags in my app.

```
const htmlData = """
          
<p>Contrary toContrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

 popular belief, Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

</p>
        
     
""";

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('flutter_html Example'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Html(
          data: htmlData,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My main issue is that that paragraph is too big and i need to add the show more and show less buttons whose code is already there.
Ny problem is how will i add that widget within the flutter_html pakage widget.

Or is there a way i can ignore the html atributes within the app

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom text style with a small font size. Something like this:

```
                Html(
                  data: yourText,
                  customTextStyle: (node, baseStyle) {
                    return baseStyle.merge(TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0));
                  },
                  
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ExpansionTile or Expandable for expanding the body on touch and collide on touching it again.
[like this](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=Kx5cY0i7&id=E2AF02AED3D438A4525698DE9A0FEFD21474723A&thid=OIP.Kx5cY0i7e_xXohDc3mSkZQAAAA&mediaurl=https%3A%2F%2F3.bp.blogspot.com%2F-aiOb3ERnmO8%2FXMLmw1GM-1I%2FAAAAAAAAAM0%2FbXNZpP0awNUOBitYWdxHw-Jmklb71mMSwCLcBGAs%2Fs1600%2Fflutter_expansion_panel.gif&exph=678&expw=382&q=Expandable%20flutter&simid=608004495329396167&ck=DD0D25F7B1FCD5C8B1020380C63019F4&selectedindex=7&form=IRPRST&ajaxhist=0&first=1&scenario=ImageBasicHover)

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Scaffold(
    body: new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: vehicles.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
      return new ExpansionTile(
        title: new Text('title'),
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            children: Text('dkjfdk')
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('flutter_html Example'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: new Stack(
          children: [
               new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10),
                child: new DraggableScrollableSheet(
                    initialChildSize: 0.8,
                    minChildSize: 0.7,
                    maxChildSize: 0.85,
                    builder: (context, scrollController) =>
                        Container(
                           hild: SingleChildScrollView(
                            controller: scrollController,
                            child: new Container(
                                child: Html(
                                  data: htmlData )
)))))
]
));
```